# Improving Our Edits Through Terms of Programmery

Tags: discussion, edits

A stated goal for editing a post is to [improve its clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Precision, accuracy and elegance in the written word are important for ensuring that complicated concepts are communicated and understood correctly by one's audience.

Unfortunately, there seems to be a terrible lack of attention or care for a very important linguistic tool: [**collective nouns**](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/collective-nouns/info).

I don't want to see the Questions and Answers of our site flounder around with  brutish and uncivil terms such as "ton", "bunch" and "lot".

For the sake of the site's reputation and standing in society, I'd like to put forth the terms of programmery<sup>1</sup> found in the answers below for consideration by and/or education of our community. It is my hope that, by introducing a modicum of sophistication and linguistic finesse, we will increase the overall civility and comity on the site.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>"Terms of Programmery" is a subcategory of collective nouns similar to [Terms of Venery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_terms_of_venery,_by_animal) but with a focus on computer science, its practitioners and subjects that matter to them.</sup>

Comment: Is this [Friday](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36918/always-friday-in-iceland)...what day is it?

Comment: It appears that a chekism of mod has arrived

Comment: @JoshCaswell - After a difficult couple weeks (workin' weekends), I made an executive decision to have an early blow-some-steam-off Friday. :)

Answer (score 3):

When editing posts on SO or MSO, consider replacing generic collective nouns with one of the more refined options below.

Keep in mind that multiple collective nouns may exist for some items, so an example has been provided for each term to help the reader choose a term that fits the context.

The following list adheres to the format:

> **Singular Term**
>
> - *Collective Noun*
>
>   > *Example of **collective noun** in a sentence.*

## Terms of Programmery

---

#### General Programming Terms

**Bug**

- *Foil*

  > *My inbox was flooded by a **foil** of bug reports.*

**GitHub Repo/Project**

- *Lacunulose*

  > *My search resulted in a **lacunulose** of GitHub Projects, none with the required feature.*

---

#### Terms Unique to Stack Overflow

**Comment**

- *Windiness*

  > *A just deleted a **windiness** of comments discussing the merits of semicolons vs periods.*

**Downvote**

- *Vigilante*

  > *I just received a **vigilante** of downvotes for no good reason.*
- *Dogpile*

  > *Referring to the question in Meta resulted in a **dogpile** of downvotes.*

**Meta Post**

- *Fury*

  > *Recent tweaks to SO's UI generated a **fury** of Meta posts explaining why we are idiots.*
- *Ignoramus*

  > *For more information, see the **ignoramus** of Meta posts concerning required comments.*

**Moderator**

- *Chekism*

  > *A real democracy would not allow a **chekism** of mods to determine what's on- or off-topic!*

**Question**

- *Chaos*

  > *The **chaos** of unclosed questions in the close vote queue has kept me up at night.*
- *Haze*

  > *I get annoyed by the **haze** of off-topic [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) questions.*

**Sock Puppet**

- *Cheat*

  > *The user created a **cheat** of sock puppets to gain trusted user privileges.*

**Suggested Edit**

- *Kindergarten*

  > *Someone just earned a badge by mass approving a **kindergarten** of suggested edits!*

**Unicorn**

[image]

- *Blessing*

  > *Whoa... why is there such a **blessing** of unicorns on Meta?*

**Upvote**

- *Giddy*

  > *How can I edit this post to earn a **giddy** of upvotes?*

Comment: Your wisdom is great. Perhaps someone should write a userscript to achieve this?

Comment: That's certainly a confusion of collective nouns.